# Wrong buffer length (const char FAR*)

Tags: c++, winapi, sockets, buffer

I have a problem, i detoured function recv(ws2_32.dll) and trying to read data. I getting as leng parametr - 17 but in real buffer is only 2 bytes length.

My code:

```
int WINAPI OwnSend(SOCKET s, const char FAR *buff, int leng, int flags )
{
    //why 'leng'==17 and (sizeof(char) * strlen(buff) + 1) == 2?
    return pTrampolineSend(s, buff, leng, flags);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to show us more code. Also, the FAR modifier has been archaic for about 15 years now; do yourself a favour and delete it.

Comment: sizeof(char)==1 by definition

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `strlen()` is not useful that way. You can't tell the length of a buffer by interpreting whatever is in it as a string. Sockets can send and receive binary data. Buffers that haven't even been initialized might contain anything.

There just happens to be a 0 byte at `buff[1]`

Answer (score 1):

len parameter is something you need to provide. You should allocate memory for buffer parameter and tell how much allocation you did with the len parameter